# PHP SMPP Implementation, constantly opening and closing sockets: is it harmful?

Tags: php, sockets, smpp

I found this SMPP Transceiver implementation:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-smppv3-4/files/

The way I use `smpp_transceiver.php`, is the following:

File `send.php`

```
require_once "smpp_transceiver.php";

...

// Open socket
$tx = new SMPP('SOME IP HERE', $port);                               // (1)
$tx->debug = false;
$tx->system_type = $systemType;
$tx->addr_npi = 1;

// Login as transmitter
$bindResult = $tx->bindTransmitter($username, $password);

$tx->sms_source_addr_npi = 1;
$tx->sms_source_addr_ton = 0;
$tx->sms_dest_addr_ton = 0;
$tx->sms_dest_addr_npi = 1;

// Send SMS
$sendResult = $tx->sendSMS($from, $to, $msg);

// Close socket
$tx->close();                                                        // (2)
$state2 = $tx->state;

// Delete object
unset($tx);
```

Very simple question:
**Is it okay to constantly open (1) and close (2) sockets?**

This `send.php` is supposed to act as a webservice.
So I will be calling this many consecutive times:

`http://...../send.php?mobile=......&body=hey`

`http://...../send.php?mobile=......&body=blah`

`http://...../send.php?mobile=......&body=zort`

`http://...../send.php?mobile=......&body=troz`

I was told that SMPP connection should be kept alive, and this is clearly not happening here.

So, two more questions:

1. How can I keep the connection alive? given that this is PHP and `smpp_transceiver.php` is a non static class. I want that every call to send.php uses the same socket connection.
2. Should I implement some kind of synchronized lock(o) to `smpp_transceiver.php` if the previous thing is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the connection alive when possible, but it's also a question of how frequently is frequent.

If "frequent" is a few times a minute, then, it's not the end of the world and carry on.
If "frequent" is a few times a second, then you may want to seek another approach for the actual SMPP portion.  PHP isn't a great choice for services that need to be kept alive for long periods of time. Try python, node or ruby.

Comment: Im actually using java (with SMSLib), but I hate the library. Too many problems with it.  Regarding your question, "frequent" means sometimes 1 sms per second. Sometimes a bundle of 300 SMS must be sent (all with different bodies), so 300 HTTP requests are made to send.php (send.jsp in my today's scenario)

Comment: Are you using php or java? That affects the answer greatly.

Comment: The three questions I did are for PHP. With my previous comment I meant that I will stopping using Java+"SMSLIB"... Sorry for confussion